# How can I display image formats not supported by the email app, e.g. TIFF?

Tags: email, images, k9-mail

As I'm using [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) for my email app, sometimes I get a tiff attached to the mail, but I cannot watch it. Even Tiff2PDF will fail :(.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture viewer of my HTC Desire work fine for TIFF...

Do you try [Astro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro)?

[BeamReader](http://www.intomobile.com/2009/11/18/beamreader-pdf-viewer-available-for-android/) is able to do it, but [it's expensive](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beamreader-pdf-viewer-full-key/com.slgmobile.beamreader.key)... However, they offer a [10-day free trial](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beamreader-pdf-viewer/com.slgmobile.beamreader).

Comment: +1 for Astro, great program.